# Angular 4 Template Driven Form Error - Exercise from " From Theory to practice E-book"

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm following instructions from Mr. Asim Hussain book and running into a console error. As a challenge to myself I'm not using plunker as the author is using for his examples, I'm using angular cli to simulate a more realistic development scenario, but I'm running into the following error:

```
ModelFormComponent.html:2 ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

   Example:


<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <input formControlName="firstName">
</div>

In your class:

this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
   firstName: new FormControl()
});
at Function.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.ReactiveErrors.missingFormException (forms.es5.js:4437)
```

Here is the link to his example on plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/MyHYNKJiB5ruiH1AOauL?p=preview

Here are my components

model.form.component.ts

```
import {
  NgModule,
  Component,
  Pipe,
  OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormsModule,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  Validators,
  FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
@Component({
  selector: 'model-form',
  template: `

  <!--suppress ALL -->
  <form novalidate [formGroup]="myform">

    <fieldset formGroupName="name">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text"
               class="form-control"
               formControlName="firstName">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text"
               class="form-control"
               formControlName="lastName">
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email"
             class="form-control"
             formControlName="email">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password"
             class="form-control"
             formControlName="password">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Language</label>
      <select class="form-control"
              formControlName="language">
        <option value="">Please select a language</option>
        <option *ngFor="let lang of langs"
                [value]="lang">{{lang}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <pre>{{myform.value | json}}</pre>
  </form>
  `
})
export class ModelFormComponent implements OnInit {
  langs: string[] = [
    'English',
    'French',
    'German',
  ]
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormGroup({
          firstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          lastName: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
        }),
        email: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("[^ @]*@[^ @]*")
      ]),
        password: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(8)
      ]),
        language: new FormControl()
    });
  }

}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModelFormComponent } from './model-form/model-form.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template:`
  {{ title }}
  <model-form></model-form>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Form Model Driven Exercise';
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ModelFormComponent } from './model-form/model-form.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ModelFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent,
    ModelFormComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is just the begging of the lecture and I'm sure there is more to getting the form working correctly, while the form loads and the app doesn't crash completly, in his plunker there are no errors, so the questions is, why Am I getting an error? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I don't see any errors in your plunker

Comment: Seems you have a typo `myform` should be `myForm`, In plunker you used `myform` everywhere while in your posted code you changed it

Comment: @yurzui - You are correct, if you move this comment to an answer I can marked as answered. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.

Replace `myform` with `myForm` in template. So it should be

```
[formGroup]="myForm"
```

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup({ ... }}
```

to the constructor. You can modify it afterwards if not all required information or data isn't yet available in the constructor.

`ngOnInit()` is called after Angular updates bindings the first time. This first time causes the error because `this.myForm` is `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Ok. moved the block as you suggested, but still getting the same warning. Any ideas?